# Как получить i-й элемент в наборе текстовой переменной?

Tags: jquery

Всем доброго дня! 
Подскажите как получить i-й элемент в строковой переменной?

```
var getvalue2 = $('td.product-price').text();
console.log(getvalue2);
```

к примеру в переменной находятся два элемента. Как получить второй?
В консоли так:

```
р.95
р.35
```

Нужно достать р.35

Comment: Судя по этому коду, у вас 2 раза этот код выполняется. И нету тут никаких вторых элементов.

Comment: вы уверены ? О_о
просто на странице два элемента с тегом td.product-price

Comment: А про какие элементы вы говорите? В "строковой переменной" находится строка, набор символов, но не jQuery-объекты или элементы DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
$('td.product-price').eq(1);
```

Comment: Barton спасибо работает!

А не подскажите из переменной можно получить это значение?
var getvalue2 = $('td.product-price').text();

Что нибудь дописать к getvalue2 что бы достать из него р.35 Интересуюсь уже в образовательных целях

Comment: getvalue2.eq(1);

Comment: var value = $('td.product-price').eq(1).html(); 

попробуйте так
или если развивая идею @eicto то, вот так 

    var getvalue2 = $('td.product-price');
    var value = getvalue2.eq(1).html();

Comment: С input то же возникли трудности
http://hashcode.ru/questions/281663

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
var getvalue2 = $('td.product-price').filter(function(index, value) {
    return index == 1;
}).text();
```